# JSON ajax returns undefined when I insert a date object in the table

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I am trying to insert the elements in a table, but when showing the data object, the undefined message is appearing

How to pass this date object to the table?

The other objects are ok, I just have a problem with the data object

JSON:

```
[
  {
    tipo: "O",
    numero: "001",
    data: { year: 2019, month: 4, day: 18 },
    prazo: 0,
    documento: "4600530888",
  },
];
```

[image: Table]

---

```
$.ajax({
      url: 'buscaTextoAditivos.action', // action to be perform
      type: 'POST',       //type of posting the data
      data: { linhaSelecionadaJson: jsonHide }, // data to set to Action Class
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function (data) {

      var indices = ['Tipo', 'Numero', 'Data', 'Prazo', 'Document']
      var table = $("<table>")
      var thead = $('<thead>')
        for (const index of indices) {
               $('<th>' + index + '</th>').appendTo(thead)
            }
               var tbody = $('<tbody>')
                for (const item of data) {
                     var tr = $('<tr>')
                        for (const index of indices) {
                            $('<td>' + item[index] + '</td>').appendTo(tr)
                        }
                        tr.appendTo(tbody)
                    }
                    tbody.appendTo(table)

                  $("#loaderMaiorDemandante").hide();
                  table.appendTo('#records_table')
```

Comment: That's not valid JSON. JSON requires quotes around property names.

Comment: [
      {
        tipo: "O",
        numero: "001",
        data: { year: 2019, month: 4, day: 18 },
        prazo: 0,
        documento: "4600530888" //fixed without comma (",").
      } //fixed without comma (",").
    ]

Comment: @D.Pardal fixed, but im still getting the undefied error when try to show the "Data"

Comment: @AllPower did you tested below code?

Comment: @Swati HISwati, Thanks for the help, it worked really well, I already accepted it as an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need two loop to iterate through values you can use one loop and access all value inside your `json` using `item.keyname` and to access json object inside json array write `item.data.keyname` .

**Demo Code** :

```js
//your response
var data = [{
    tipo: "O",
    numero: "001",
    data: {
      year: 2019,
      month: 4,
      day: 18
    },
    prazo: 1,
    documento: "4600530888"
  },
  {
    tipo: "O",
    numero: "001",
    data: {
      year: 2009,
      month: 4,
      day: 18
    },
    prazo: 0,
    documento: "4600530588"
  }
]
var indices = ['Tipo', 'Numero', 'Document', 'Prazo','Data']
var table = $("<table border='1'>")
var thead = $('<thead>')
for (const index of indices) {

  $('<th>' + index + '</th>').appendTo(thead)
}
var tbody = $('<tbody>')
for (const item of data) {
  var tr = $('<tr>')
  //get datas from json 
  $('<td>' + item.tipo + '</td>').appendTo(tr)
  $('<td>' + item.numero + '</td>').appendTo(tr)
  $('<td>' + item.prazo + '</td>').appendTo(tr)
  $('<td>' + item.documento + '</td>').appendTo(tr)
   $("<td>" + item.data.year + "/" + item.data.month + "/" + item.data.day + "</td>").appendTo(tr)
    tr.appendTo(tbody)

}
//apend data in thead 
thead.appendTo(table)
tbody.appendTo(table)

$("#loaderMaiorDemandante").hide();
table.appendTo('#records_table')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="records_table"></div>
```